# How can I check a confusion_matrix after fine-tuning with custom datasets?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

This question is the same with [How can I check a confusion_matrix after fine-tuning with custom datasets?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/99815/how-can-i-check-a-confusion-matrix-after-fine-tuning-with-custom-datasets), on Data Science Stack Exchange.

### Background

I would like to check a confusion_matrix, including precision, recall, and f1-score like below after fine-tuning with custom datasets.

Fine tuning process and the task are [Sequence Classification with IMDb Reviews](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#sequence-classification-with-imdb-reviews) on the [Fine-tuning with custom datasets tutorial on Hugging face](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#fine-tuning-with-trainer).

After finishing the fine-tune with Trainer, how can I check a confusion_matrix in this case?

An image of confusion_matrix, including precision, recall, and f1-score [original site](http://www.renom.jp/notebooks/product/renom_dl/trainer/notebook.html): just for example output image

```
predictions = np.argmax(trainer.test(test_x), axis=1)

# Confusion matrix and classification report.
print(classification_report(test_y, predictions))

            precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.75      0.79      0.77      1000
          1       0.81      0.87      0.84      1000
          2       0.63      0.61      0.62      1000
          3       0.55      0.47      0.50      1000
          4       0.66      0.66      0.66      1000
          5       0.62      0.64      0.63      1000
          6       0.74      0.83      0.78      1000
          7       0.80      0.74      0.77      1000
          8       0.85      0.81      0.83      1000
          9       0.79      0.80      0.80      1000

avg / total       0.72      0.72      0.72     10000
```

### Code

```py
from transformers import DistilBertForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=3,              # total number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=10,
)

model = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,                         # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments, defined above
    train_dataset=train_dataset,         # training dataset
    eval_dataset=val_dataset             # evaluation dataset
)

trainer.train()
```

### What I did so far

Data set Preparation for [Sequence Classification with IMDb Reviews](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#sequence-classification-with-imdb-reviews), and I'm fine-tuning with Trainer.

```
from pathlib import Path

def read_imdb_split(split_dir):
    split_dir = Path(split_dir)
    texts = []
    labels = []
    for label_dir in ["pos", "neg"]:
        for text_file in (split_dir/label_dir).iterdir():
            texts.append(text_file.read_text())
            labels.append(0 if label_dir is "neg" else 1)

    return texts, labels

train_texts, train_labels = read_imdb_split('aclImdb/train')
test_texts, test_labels = read_imdb_split('aclImdb/test')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_texts, val_texts, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(train_texts, train_labels, test_size=.2)

from transformers import DistilBertTokenizerFast
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

train_encodings = tokenizer(train_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)
val_encodings = tokenizer(val_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(test_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)

import torch

class IMDbDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

train_dataset = IMDbDataset(train_encodings, train_labels)
val_dataset = IMDbDataset(val_encodings, val_labels)
test_dataset = IMDbDataset(test_encodings, test_labels)
```

Comment: Check for the comment, I wrote it from scratch now, if you have problems we can solve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do in this situation is to iterate on the validation set(or on the test set for that matter) and manually create a list of `y_true` and `y_pred`.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from sklearn import metrics
 
y_preds = []
y_trues = []
for index,val_text in enumerate(val_texts):
     tokenized_val_text = tokenizer([val_text], 
                                    truncation=True,
                                    padding=True,
                                    return_tensor='pt')
     logits = model(tokenized_val_text)
     prediction = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
     y_pred = torch.argmax(prediction).numpy()
     y_true = val_labels[index]
     y_preds.append(y_pred)
     y_trues.append(y_true)
```

Finally,

```
confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_trues, y_preds, labels=["neg", "pos"]))
print(confusion_matrix)
```

Observations:

1. The output of the model are the `logits`, not the probabilities normalized.
2. As such, we apply `softmax` on dimension one to transform to actual probabilities (e.g. `0.2% class 0`, `0.8% class 1`).
3. We apply the `.argmax()` operation to get the index of the class.

Comment: The softmax is redundant here, as it's monotonic, so the argmax will give the same results on the logits as the probability-like outputs of the softmax.

Comment: Totally agree, I wanted for the OP to see the actual probabilities.